# JPA customizations return DTOs

Tags: mysql, jpa, java-11

I tried using a multi-table query to return a custom DTO,here is the SQL I wrote

```
 select t.item_code,t.item_name,t.item_close,t.sum_risk,t.industry,c.net_workth,b.institutional_count as institutional
from (
     select t.item_code, item_tag.item_name, t.sum_risk, item_tag.industry, tick.item_close
     from item_tag
              join (select sum(pct_chg) as sum_risk, item_code
                    from item_tick
                    group by item_code) as t
                   on t.item_code = item_tag.item_code
              join (select item_close, item_code from item_tick group by item_code order by trade_date desc) as tick
                   on tick.item_code = item_tag.item_code
     order by t.sum_risk desc
 ) as t
     join (
select sum(buy) - sum(sell) as net_workth, item_code
from institutional_trad
group by item_code
order by net_workth desc
 )
    
 as c on t.item_code = c.item_code
     join (
select count(exchange) as institutional_count,item_code from institutional_trad group by item_code 
  ) as b
          on t.item_code =  b.item_code
  order by t.sum_risk desc
```

My SQL execution in the datagrip is normal return results,however, when using a native query in JPA, an exception that cannot be converted occurs. The message is as follows

```
 org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.zillink.core.model.analysis.ItemResult]
```

This is what I define in the structure of the DTO :

```
  package com.zillink.core.model.analysis;
  import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
  import lombok.Data;
  import javax.persistence.ColumnResult;
  import javax.persistence.ConstructorResult;
  import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;
  import java.math.BigDecimal;
  @Data
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "item_result",
    classes = {
            @ConstructorResult(
                    targetClass = com.zillink.core.model.analysis.ItemResult.class,
                    columns = {
                            @ColumnResult(name = "item_code", type = String.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name = "item_name", type = String.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name = "item_close", type = BigDecimal.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name = "sum_risk", type = BigDecimal.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name = "net_workth", type = BigDecimal.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name = "institutional", type = Long.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name = "industry", type = String.class)
                    }
            )
    }
    )
    
public class ItemResult {
  String itemCode;


String itemName;

BigDecimal itemClose;

BigDecimal sumRisk;

BigDecimal netWorkth;

Long institutional;

String industry;
}
```

JPA is written like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemTickRepository extends JpaRepository<ItemTick, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ItemTick> {
@Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "select t.item_code ,t.item_name ,t.item_close ,t.sum_risk ,t.industry,c.net_workth ,b.institutional_count as institutional \n" +
        "from (\n" +
        "         select t.item_code, item_tag.item_name, t.sum_risk, item_tag.industry, tick.item_close\n" +
        "         from item_tag\n" +
        "                  join (select sum(pct_chg) as sum_risk, item_code\n" +
        "                        from item_tick\n" +
        "                        group by item_code) as t\n" +
        "                       on t.item_code = item_tag.item_code\n" +
        "                  join (select item_close, item_code from item_tick group by item_code order by trade_date desc) as tick\n" +
        "                       on tick.item_code = item_tag.item_code\n" +
        "         order by t.sum_risk desc\n" +
        "     ) as t\n" +
        "         join (\n" +
        "    select sum(buy) - sum(sell) as net_workth, item_code\n" +
        "    from institutional_trad\n" +
        "    group by item_code\n" +
        "    order by net_workth desc\n" +
        ")\n" +
        "    as c on t.item_code = c.item_code\n" +
        "join (\n" +
        "     select count(exchange) as institutional_count,item_code from institutional_trad group by item_code\n" +
        "    ) as b\n" +
        "on t.item_code =  b.item_code\n" +
        "order by t.sum_risk desc\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\n")
List<ItemResult> findAllByHistory();
```

}

I've been searching with Google long enough to know that using the @SqlResultSetMapping annotation would help me implement the return of a custom type, but it's getting an exception,why is that

my development framework is:

```
 Spring the boot: 2.4.3
 Spring jpa: 2.4.3
 Mysql version: 8.x
```

Comment: The column aliases in the native query must match the `DTO` property names

Comment: Instead of creating a complex query like this, you can create a view and map your entity to that view.